# ItemCount not working in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, spservices, item

I used the following code in SharePoint 2010 to get itemCount from a list

```
itemCount = $(xData.responseXML.xml).find("rs\\:data, data").attr("ItemCount");
```

But when I use it in SharePoint 2013, its not working. Any work around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount");
```

Hope it will works for you.